# Can I have multiple INSERT statements following the same WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am defining a new WITH statement as newStaff, and then I am taking that data and filling it into other tables. It doesn't seem to let me reference my newStaff table more than once with  a FROM statement. SSMS tells me newStaff is an invalid object name on the second INSERT statement.

```
WITH newStaff AS (
  SELECT
    dat.staffnumber,
    dat.firstname,
    dat.middlename,
    dat.lastname,
    dat.suffix,
    dat.sex,
    dat.birthdate,
    dat.race
FROM dataTable dat
WHERE 1=1
 AND dat.staffnumber is not null
)

INSERT INTO newStaffNameTable(
  staffID,
  firstname,
  middlename,
  lastname,
  suffix)
SELECT
  ns.staffnumber,
  ns.firstname,
  ns.middlename,
  ns.lastname,
  ns.suffix
FROM newStaff ns
WHERE 1=1

INSERT INTO newStaffDemographicTable(
  staffID,
  gender,
  birthdate,
  race)
SELECT
  nsdem.staffnumber,
  nsdem.sex,
  nsdem.birthdate,
  nsdem.race
FROM newStaff nsdem
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: A Common Table Expression (CTE) is, as it's name suggests, an **expression**; it is part of the statement it is defined in and that's it.

Comment: You want a temp table (or table variable) if you want to use the results more than once.

Comment: In fact reading the docs would have answered your question `Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined within the execution scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement.`

Comment: No, Common Table Expressions are not perisited between statements. You could make a view instead, persist the data to a temp table or table variable, or repeat the CTE code.

Comment: To be honest not sure why this even needs a CTE. It's a really simple single condition `WHERE dat.staffnumber is not null` you could just write it out twice